# Can I write an rqt plugin with QML?

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm interested in writing a virtual gauge plugin for rqt. It seems the easiest way to do this would be the "Circular Gauge" [QML type](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickEnterpriseControls/qml-qtquick-enterprise-controls-circulargauge.html). And I have seen that @Boris wrote a [ROS interface](http://answers.ros.org/question/238095/how-can-i-do-a-gui/) for QML. But, I haven't seen anybody use QML for an rqt plugin yet. Is that possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248848/can-i-write-an-rqt-plugin-with-qml?/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2016-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like ros_qml is a python script that loads QML as python QT application: https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml/blob/master/src/ros_qml/__init__.py , so it might be possible to adapt that to run inside of an rqt plugin instead of as a standalone application.

I'm not sure what else rqt_qml is doing during the setup (the setup documentation refers to running scripts that don't exist, which makes it hard to follow), but it looks like there may be some quirks that are required to get the ros_qml plugins available within QML.

The dependency on Qt 5.4 is also much newer than the default version of QT that is used by most versions of ROS. (Versions before Kinetic used QT 4.x , and Kinetic uses QT 5.3: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html ). It's not possible to use multiple versions of QT in the same application, so you'll want to make sure that QML is compatible with the version of QT that's used by rqt before you start experimenting too much.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-11-26**:
@ahendrix Which missing scripts are you referring to? To me everything seems in place. Anyway, the shell scripts are only used to set up correct development environment. The python init script is basically doing the same: it inserts appropriate paths to QT environment.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-26**:
The first section of the directions refer to a `configure.py`, but there's no configure.py in ros_qml.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-11-26**:
Right, but that refers to `PyQt` installation, not `ros_qml`. Namely, the line before shell snippet reads *To install PyQt with Python 2.7 bindings configure and build it with the following parameters (actual paths may differ)*.